# How to scrape value or url, src and title using dweidner/laravel-goutte?

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, goutte

[laravel-goutte](https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte)

```
$crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'https://examplesite.com/');

$crawler->filter('.blog')->each(function ($node) {

$uri = $node->html(); // $uri value is written below
    dump($uri);
});
```

here is the value of $uri ,

```
$uri = """<div class="blog" >
    <a class="url" href="/blog/url">
        <div class="blog-screenshot">
            <img src="/blog/img/img.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <span class="details">More Info</span>
        <div class="author">By <span class="author">John Doe</span></div>
        <h3 class="blog-title">BLOG TITLE</h3>
    </a>
    <div class="blog-actions">
        <a class="blog-preview" href="/blog/preview/url">Preview</a>
    </div>
</div>"""
```

Now, how can i extract url href, img, src, title and action from $uri?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$crawler->filter('.blog')->each(function ($node) {

    $blogUrl        =  $node->find('.url', 0)->attr('href');

    $screenshotSrc  =  $node->find('.blog-screenshot > img', 0)->attr('src');

    $title          =  $node->find('.blog-title', 0)->text();

    $previewUrl     =  $node->find('.blog-preview', 0)->attr('href');

});
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked but with some modification !
$crawler->filter('.blog')->each(function ($node) {

    $blogUrl        =  $node->filter('.url')->link()->getUri();

    $screenshotSrc  =  $node->filter('img')->attr('src');

    $title          =  $node->filter('.blog-title')->text();
    $previewUrl     =  $node->filter('.blog-preview')->attr('href');

});